# Map not getting loaded and showing error in android

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi I am Struggling for two days, in my Map Application Map is not displayed  and getting the below error.. i Searched lot and din't get any proper solution yet..

Xml File

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.googlegpstracker;

     import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

     import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;

     public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

mainfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.googlegpstracker"
android:versionCode="1"
```

android:versionName="1.0" >

```
 <uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="17"
 android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

     <permission
   android:name="com.example.googlegpstracker.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature" />



 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlegpstracker.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
   android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <activity
  android:name="com.example.googlegpstracker.MainActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name" >
     <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyC0hlJU8lEbvXmqckdUHHRhRoRkF0KpYR8" />
        </application>

   </manifest>
```

And below is my Logcat

```
     06-22 13:53:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
           06-22 13:53:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1638): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable       to start activity        ComponentInfo{com.example.googlegpstracker/com.example.googlegpstracker.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
06-22 13:53:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-22 13:53:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-22 13:53:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-22 13:53:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-22 13:53:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-22 13:53:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-22 13:53:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-22 13:53:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 13:53:41.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-22 13:55:22.367: E/AndroidRuntime(1707): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path: /data/app/com.example.googlegpstracker-1.apk
06-22 13:55:22.367: E/AndroidRuntime(1707):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
06-22 13:55:22.367: E/AndroidRuntime(1707):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-22 13:55:22.367: E/AndroidRuntime(1707):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-22 13:55:22.367: E/AndroidRuntime(1707):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
```

Comment: Does R.menu.main exist?
Does your application run without the fragment?

Comment: yes its executing without fragment\

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have the Google Play Services SDK referenced as a library project, which would explain why the class cannot be found.  Since com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment is only referenced in xml, it would come up at run time and you wouldn't catch it before running the app.

Check out:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code

And here for info about setting up the SDK:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this.before this make sure that you have google API and you entered proper key and all in you.

`

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />      
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />    
    </intent-filter>

</activity>

<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

`